# Let $P$ be a fixed point $(3,4)$ and $Q$ the point $(x,\sqrt{25-x^2})$.If $M(x)$ is the slope of the line $PQ$,find $\lim_{x\to 3}M(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P$ be a fixed point $(3,4)$ and $Q$ the point $(x,\sqrt{25-x^2})$.If $M(x)$ is the slope of the line $PQ$,find $\lim_{x\to 3}M(x)$

My work:
Calculating Q at the given limit for x, I get $Q(3,4)$.So I get the slope $0$. Am I getting the correct answer or is there something I am missing out on? I felt that I am doing something wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Justify each step in the following

$$M(x)=\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}-4}{x-3}=\frac{25-x^2-16}{(x-3)\left(\sqrt{25-x^2}+4\right)}=$$

$$=\;-\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{25-x^2}+4}\xrightarrow[x\to 3]{}-\frac3{4}$$

Comment: Yes...It is actually correct...I was thinking of using something like this...but had a mental block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The slope (definition of slope?) isn't 0, is:
$$M(x)={\sqrt{25-x^2}-4\over x-3}.$$